# tslint error in template with angular material autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

On an angular 4 app, I use the **material** component **autocomplete**, very similarly to the example given on the documentation :

```
<md-form-field>
   <input type="text" mdInput [formControl]="myControl"  [mdAutocomplete]="auto">
</md-form-field>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
   <md-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
      {{ option }}
   </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

I also use **tslint** and I have an error in my template file because of the syntax `[mdAutocomplete]="auto"`:

```
The property "auto" that you're trying to access does not exist in the class declaration.
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a codelyzer issue. See this [link](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/issues/303) and this [issue](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/issues/297#issuecomment-296857427):

> Problem exist in codelyzer 3.0.1 ( vs tslint@^5.0.0), however, is
>   fixed in codelyzer3.0.0-beta.1 (vs tslint@^4.0.0).

As a work around, use `@ViewChild` in your typescript class.

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
// ....

// Get the 'auto' element in your component class
@ViewChild('auto') auto: ElementRef;
```